# Fix/Align a Nested Row to the Bottom of it's Parent Column in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, position

Align/fix a nested row to the bottom of its parent column (`col-md-x`) in bootstrap 3 ?

Here is the bs3 result:

[image]

Here what I want:

[image]

The nested `div.row` should be affixed even to the bottom of the right-hand column

[JSFiddle of current code](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/8rb6evtk/3/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <p>...</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to include your own code samples to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved using a little extra CSS that brings flexbox-like functionality to bootstrap*

Edit your HTML by adding these two classes:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-eq-height"> <!--  add the .row-eq-height class -->
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <p>...</p>
            <div class="row bottom"> <!-- add the .bottom class -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The add these classes to your CSS:

```
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

DEMOS:

[as coded in this answer](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/8rb6evtk/1/)

[with added styling for clarity](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/8rb6evtk/2/)

Reference:

[thanks acmetech](http://acmetech.github.io/todc-bootstrap-3/examples/equal-height-columns/)

*the display flex property used to achieve this is only compatible back to IE9

Answer (score 0):

According to Bootstrap 3 documentation, fix-to-bottom of a given container can be implemented by add `.navbar-fixed-bottom` class.

[Reference link - **Fixed to bottom**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom)

Comment: this is not what the op asked for, this sticks the element to the bottom of the whole page, as opposed to sticking it to the bottom of the parent element.